# Product ID Link

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to display a product ID with a link in it but I cant seem to get it right. It the ID and the link that im having problems with.

Iv copied the script form another document which is working fine.

```
require "db.inc";

// open connection 
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Unable to     connect!"); 

// select database 
mysql_select_db($databaseName) or die ("Unable to select database!"); 

// create query 
$query = "SELECT * FROM protien"; 
//Check initial letter
// execute query 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 

// see if any rows were returned 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
// yes 
// print them one after another 
echo "<table cellpadding=10 border=0>"; 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<th>" ?>Image<?php "</th>"; 
    echo "<th>" ?>Brand<?php "</th>";
    echo "<th>" ?>Type<?php "</th>";
    echo "<th>" ?>Price<?php "</th>";
    echo "<th>" ?>Description<?php "</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo"<td>""<a href=Ammend.php?memberID=.$row['memberID']>.$row['memberID'].</a>""    </td>";
    echo "<td>"."<img src=../Products/".$row['ProductImage']."> </td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['ProductBrand']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row['ProductType']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>£".$row['ProductPrice']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['ProductDescription']."</td>";


    echo "</tr>"; 
  } 
  echo "</table>"; 
 } 
 else { 
  // no 
 // print status message 
 echo "No rows found!"; 
}
```

Comment: The syntax highlighter shows your error

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))??? It shud be while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))!!!

Comment: @user2401175 Im not sure that it is. Iv updated the scripted and added more. You know more than me so if you still think this let me know cheers

Comment: You need to learn basic PHP syntax and `echo`ing before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first "td" row should be like this

```
echo "<td><a href=Ammend.php?memberID=" . $row['memberID'] . ">" . $row['memberID'] . "</a> </td>";
```

You need to provide us with your output to see where the error is but I think you've got the idea...